# setText to another activity?

Tags: java, android, settext

I have a button on an activity called "HomePage". When you click the button, I want it to setText to a TextView called "weaponTitle" on a separate activity, called ItemSelection. Though, when I run the setText, it gives the error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method `void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)` on a `null` object reference

So this means it can't find the TextView "weaponTitle". Is there a good way to do fix this? I have made sure I set up everything correctly too!

Here is the sliver of code I forgot to share!

```
new displayPrices(weaponTitle, "Genuine Freedom Staff");
```

Comment: You should share code for both the activity. If you are trying to print something from one activity to another, use intents to pass the data.

Comment: Do you have a sample code for the intent? I tried looking for a good example, but couldn't find any!

Comment: Do you want to change the another Activity's text when you jump to it?

Comment: you want to get the text from a null object reference,this is the problem :-     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420945/java-lang-nullpointerexception-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-on-a-null-objec

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7325248/1099716

Comment: That, is not the problem. I have tried using another TextView inside the main activity, and it works just fine. So its the TextView's problem, NOT a null object

Comment: please explain, when second activity is visible

Comment: In the button code, it runs two things. One to set the text of the TextView in another activity, then it switches to the next Activity

Answer (score 2):

try this

**Firstclass**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext,SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("KEY",value);
        intent.putExtra("KEY",VALUE);
        startActivity(intent)
```

**Second Activity**

```
 Intent intent =getIntent();
 confirm_txt =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
 String txt_put =intent.getStringExtra("KEY");
 confirm_tId.setText(txt_put);
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside oncrete of your HomePage Activity

```
Button yourbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button_id);
         yourbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Perform action on click
                 Intent intent = new Intent(HomePage.this, ItemSelection.class);
                intent.putExtra("weapontitle",value);
                startActivity(intent);
             }
         });
```

Inside ItemSelection Activity's oncreate

```
Intent intent =getIntent();
String txt =intent.getStringExtra("weapontitle");
TextView weaponTitle =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_weaponTitle);
weaponTitle.setText(txt);
```

Comment: I tried this, but for some reason, the title then becomes blank, with nothing in it

Comment: make sure that value in intent.putExtra("weapontitle",value); is not empty, for testing hardcore a string value for value like this in  intent.putExtra("weapontitle","test String);

Answer (score 0):

go through this way,

***pass this from your first activity***,

```
Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, ChangePasswordActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("savedUser", savedUser);
        Log.e("username", "--->>" + savedUser);
        startActivity(i);
```

***in second activity , get this as below***

```
Intent extras = getIntent();
        savedUser = extras.getStringExtra("savedUser");
        Log.e("savedUser", "--->>" + savedUser);
```

Now you can set text as you got it on other activity.

```
etUsername.setText(userName);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("weaponTitle","Genuine Freedom Staff");
        startActivity(intent);
```

In the second activity you do:

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
String weaponName = bundle.getString("weaponTitle");



TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
   textView.setText(weaponName);
```