# NullPointerException for no reason

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, textview

I am trying to set a `TextView`'s text but every time I try to cast a virtual method, it throws a `NullPointerException`. As you can see, the widget exists and I am creating a `TextView` variable with the correct id.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/searchDispensaryName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/productPicture"
    android:layout_marginTop="13sp"
    android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

TextView dispensaryName = (TextView) costumView.findViewById(R.id.searchDispensaryName);
```

Here is where the exception is thrown:

```
dispensaryName.setText(object.get("dispensary_name").toString());
```

And here is the exception text:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.dragosandrei.greenkinexdorian.SearchCostumeAdapter.getView(SearchCostumeAdapter.java:47)
                  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2411)
                  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1986)
                  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:709)
                  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:770)
                  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1749)
                  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2210)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17688)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17688)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17688)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17688)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
                  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1193)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17688)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:325)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17688)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1762)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1606)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1515)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17688)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:325)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17688)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1762)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1606)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1515)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17688)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:325)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:774)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17688)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2513)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2228)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1366)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6768)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:926)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:735)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:667)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:912)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

There is literally no reason for this exception to be thrown! Can you tell me if and where I am wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420945/java-lang-nullpointerexception-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-on-a-null-objec)

Comment: What is `costumView` you're calling `findViewById()` on?

Comment: `costumView`...let me chech

Comment: Are you sure that `costumView` contains your TextView? If yes, you could try to **Clean** then **Rebuild** again your project. Maybe Android Studio error.

Comment: `View costumView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_costume_raw, parent, false);`

Comment: Assuming that layout contains `searchDispensaryName`, then you need to post more of your `getView()` adapter code.

Answer (score 2):

costumView.findViewById you sure that's how it works?
try using findViewById without costumView

```
TextView dispensaryName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.searchDispensaryName);
```

Comment: You know you can edit your answer instead of writing comments right?

Comment: It's inside an `ArrayAdapter<Object>`

Comment: You were right about the `costumView`, but not where you think. It was a view created by me to make a costume raw for a `ListView`. The problem was that i was returning a `convertView`